# Plot variable size/color-heatmap for mulitple occurences of points in scatter plot

Tags: numpy, plot, matplotlib

I'm stuck with the following problem and I hope I can explain it coherent.

So, I have a number (about 10) of descrete positions on a coordinate system.

Now, I want to analyse data from a program where user could label each point as somethingA and somethingB.

I extracted the data points for each class. So I have about 60 points for the somethingA class and a little bit less for the other class. One class stands for good points and one for bad points. I want to find the positions which have the most good/bad labels. I do that with machine learning algorithms, I just want to visualize this with plots.

I now want to plot those points. So I make one plot per class. But since in every class every point occurs at least once, the two plots would look exactly the same.
But, the amount of occurences has a different distribution thoughout the positions.
Maybe point A has 20 occurences in class A and 1 in class B, both plots would look the same.

So, my question is: How can I take the number of occurences for points into account when plotting scatters in Matplotlib?

Either with different colors (like a heatmap?) maybe with a cool legend.
Or with different sizes (e.g. higher amount = bigger cirlce).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you but I have had a problem where I wanted a scatterplot to reflect both positions as well as two variables that were attributed to the data points.

Since size and color in the scatter function do not allow variables themselves, meaning one has to specify color code and size in the usual way, meaning sth like

```
        ax.scatter(..., c=whatEverFunction, s=numberOfOccurences, ...)
```

did not work for me.

what I did was to bin the values of the two variables I wanted to visualize. In my case the variable `nodeMass` and another variable.

```
for i in range(Number):
    mask[i] = False
    if(lowerBound1<variableOne[i]<upperBound1):
        mask[i] = True & pmask[i]
    if len(positionX[mask])>0:
        ax.scatter(positionX[mask], positionY[mask], positionZ[mask],C='#424242',s=10, edgecolors='none')
for i in range(Number):
    mask[i] = False
    if(lowerBound2<variableOne[i]<upperBound2):
        mask[i] = True & pmask[i]
if len(positionX[mask])>0:
       ax.scatter(positionX[mask], positionY[mask], positionZ[mask],c='#9E0050',s=25,edgecolors='none')
```

I know it is not very elegant but it worked for me. I had to make as many for loops as I had bins in my variables. With if-querys and the masks I could at least avoid redundant or 'unreadable' plots.

Comment: Aaah, okay. Thanks for sharing your solution. I'll try it out for my case.